# What's the meaning of these Shakespearean English sentences being used in here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

[Source](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/toi-editorials/its-nice-to-kiss-by-this-book-indians-love-to-play-juliet-to-shakespeares-romeo/)

> Cleopatra, Othello, Romeo and Juliet, they all blend in because **forsooth here** that whole dying for love or killing for love business is verily a sweet sorrow. A special shout out also to the witches; **we love them three**.
>
> Later it’s all a great help at the workplace – **there’s daggers in men’s smiles, you’re alerted.**

Comment: +1 for context but could you at least show (that means include a link) that you looked up the words *forsooth* and *daggers* and have understood what they mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard the expression "to name-drop"?  You "name-drop" if you like to add certain famous people's names to a conversation to add to you own reputation.

A similar activity is to selectively throw in quotes, particularly Shakespearean quotes, to try and impress other people with your education and intelligence.  Sometimes it works, but usually only if you do it selectively and use a quote perfectly appropriate to the context.  It doesn't work well if you toss in quotes willy-nilly, like too many croutons in a salad.

In this case the quotes are inappropriate and sprinkled liberally in like croutons, but I can't tell if the author is trying to be funny or trying to make fun of Indians who are too fond of Shakespearean quotes and use them out of context.  It could be subtle satire, or it could just be bad writing.